# Амперсенд и двойное двоеточие перед функцией в С++

Tags: c++

Есть следующий код: `::std::thread a(&::func);`. Что значит такая запись: `&::`?

Answer (score 4):

Это два отдельных оператора. Оператор `&`- это взятие адреса, то есть получение указателя на функцию.

Оператор `::` - это оператор разрешения области видимости. Если слева от него ничего нет, то он означает глобальную область видимости.